# Set ArangoDB to be case insensitive

Tags: arangodb, case-insensitive

I want to know if there is a way to set the entire database, or at least the collections, to be case insensitive without having to use lower() or upper() in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible to have a full collection to be case insensitive.

You could create a view that will index you collection and specify a default analyzer that will ignore the case.

See:

- ArangoSearch: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/arangosearch.html
- `norm` property for analyzers: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/analyzers.html#norm

Comment: But using lower() or upper() will not slow down the query?

Answer (score 0):

You you are worrying about query-time performance you could you injection-time approach like:

```
LET doc = {
    originalText: "Some Text",
    searchText: LOWER("Some Text")
}

INSERT doc INTO yourCollection
```

The AQL:

```
FOR doc IN yourCollection
    FILTER doc.searchText == LOWER("your search term")
    RETURN doc
```